# Analytically solving simple quadratic problem in single variable with boundary constraints

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem where $x$ is scalar variable.

$$
\min_x \dfrac12ax^2 + bx \\ subject\ to:\ l\le x \le u
$$

$ a > 0 $ therefore, this is a convex optimization problem. Without the boundary constraints the problem has a trivial solution $ x = -\frac{b}{a} $. But how do the constraints affect the solutions at the boundaries and how to get a rigorous analytical solution?

**Context:**
I am trying to understand the derivations in this [paper](http://ntu.csie.org/~cjlin/papers/cddual.pdf). The original problem, of which I have given a simplified version, appears in eqns (6-9). The authors talk about the projected gradient and give different values of the projected gradient at the boundaries. I did not understand this part.

Comment: In your case the minimum is at $-b/a$ if it lies in the interval. If not, then by symmetry it's given by the $x$ closest to it.

Comment: @davin, Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I have corrected it. But I would like a rigorous solution something like the one given in the paper (which I did not completely follow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that $f(x)$ attains its minimum on the boundary if $-b/a$ is not in the interval via contradiction. Suppose the minimizer is inside, $l \leq x_\ast \leq u$. The gradient at $x_\ast$ is nonzero, which means either $x_\ast + t$ or $x_\ast - t$ for small $t$ can attain a strictly smaller value  by considering linear approximation (in this case, if derivative is positive, then consider $x_\ast - t$ for small $t$).

In general, can reason similarly for higher dimensions. If the gradient does not vanish at a point $x$, and a feasible direction $p$ (i.e. $x+tp$ also feasible for $t>0$)  satisfies $\nabla f^T p < 0$, then you were not at a local optimum, as $x+tp$ can decrease the objective further.

Ah! One more point: If you have a local optimum, since the problem is convex, it is necessarily the global optimum.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible analytical solution that I came up with. Rewrite the problem as 
$$ \min_{l\le x \le u} \dfrac{a}2[x-(-b/a)]^2\equiv \min_{l\le x \le u} [x-(-b/a)]^2$$

Therefore we are trying to find a point $x^*$ in the interval  $[l,u]$ which minimizes the distance from the point $-b/a$. This can be dealt with in a case by case basis

Case I: $-b/a < l \implies x^* = l $

Case II: $-b/a > u \implies x^* = u $

Case III: $ l \le -b/a \le u \implies x^* = -b/a $